# Adding colorbar to a 3 variable colour graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

From another post I got how to create the graph, but am struggling to add a scale bar.
Printing an item from colors gives `[ 0.53800422  0.67490159  0.99172189  1.]` which i'm guessing is the scaled color?

```
my_array = range(20)
my_array2 = my_array
z = np.array(my_array)    
x = np.asarray(my_array)    
scaled_x = (x - x.min()) / x.ptp()
scaled_z = (z - z.min()) / z.ptp()
colors = plt.cm.coolwarm(scaled_z)
graph = plt.scatter(my_array, my_array2, c = colors, cmap = colors )
cb = plt.colorbar(graph)
cb.set_label('mean value')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've gotten slightly mixed up on what the `cmap` argument is supposed to be.  It's either a colormap object (e.g. `plt.cm.coolwarm`) or the name of a colormap (e.g. `"coolwarm"`).

You're trying to pass in explicit colors. (The `[ 0.53800422 0.67490159 0.99172189 1.]` is the red, green, blue, and alpha values that the colormap would yield for one of your specific data points.)

Instead of calculating explicit colors, pass in the colormap object directly.

For example, given your example code above, you could re-write it as:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

my_array = np.arange(20)
my_array2 = my_array
z = my_array

graph = plt.scatter(my_array, my_array2, c=z, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm)
cb = plt.colorbar(graph)
cb.set_label('mean value')

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you'd like, you could also use a slightly different style:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(20)
y, z = x, x

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
graph = ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap='coolwarm', s=200)
cb = fig.colorbar(graph)

cb.set_label('Mean Value', rotation=-90, va='bottom')
ax.margins(0.1)

plt.show()
```

[image]